# How to create a second set of tags that use the same slug or URL?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, slug

Is there a way to create a second set of tags that can use the same slug or URL?

Normally, an example set of tags will look like this by default on a WordPress blog page:

`■ tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6`

With two set of tags, I'm trying to create something like this:

`■ tag3, tag4 | tag1, tag2, tag5, tag6`

In other words, I'm trying to get `tag3` and `tag4` to be in the front, and use the same slug or URL as the other four.

I recently learned how to create a custom taxonomy, thanks to [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/),
but it turns out I can't use the same slug or URL for multiple custom taxonomies.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple taxonomies if all you want to do is customize the order in which they are rendered. A plugin like one of these can help your order your categories, tags and taxonomies:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-taxonomy-order-ne/

Is there something more specific you are trying to achieve?

Comment: both addons work great, but is there a way to get a second tag box in the post editor? here's an image of what I'm trying to get: http://i282.photobucket.com/albums/kk246/leeV18/web/help2_zpsvtu5r5ud.png